# overflow of the multiplication of unsigned long long int

Tags: c++, g++, unsigned-long-long-int

I have doubt about the multiplication of unsigned long long int in the G++ 5.4.0 compiler. Why the 1st snippet overflows even though the variable n is unsigned long long int type? Why the 'LL' behind 8 works?

Please give me some keyword that I can dig more about this problem. Thanks!

```
//WRONG RESULT: 1549413176
int main(){
  unsigned long long int n = 1804289383;
  std::cout<<n * 8 <<endl;
  return 0;
}

//Correct :14434315064
int main(){
  unsigned long long int n = 1804289383;
  std::cout<<n * 8LL <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

compiler: g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Unable to reproduce with gcc 6.2

Comment: And this seems to be dependent on the compilers because the 1st snippet works fine in my VS2015. Please correct me if my observation is wrong

Comment: Cannot reproduce on gcc 5.3: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OfuG6PbOpe3Wwmo5 Could you try to put a testcase in an online compiler like wandbox, coliru or ideone?

Comment: @krzaq Thank you for share the wandbox website to me. It's an awesome website!!  Actually, I guess this is probably an issue in g++ 5.4.0. But unfortunately, there's no g++ 5.4.0 on wandbox. But the problem can be reproduced in the following online coding website which is said to use g++ 5.4.0 as their compiler for C++ language.  https://leetcode.com/problems/arranging-coins/

Comment: https://leetcode.com/faq/  @krzaq

Comment: It could also be that 8 is an int and the result is being casted to an int.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on GCC 4.8.5. I agree with Nick- you probably accidentally casted the result to an int (which gives the stated wrong result).